# Query resources used by using az pipelines CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

We are using yaml pipelines in Azure DevOps. Our pipeline is using multiple repositories which we select in "resources" tab.
I need to create a powershell script that will fetch the data from these pipelines, namely branch name and commit id of one of the repositories that we select in resources.
So far, the only info I was able to get is the branch, repo name, and commit ID of the "main" repository, ie the one where the yaml pipeline is located.

Is there any way to do this via CLI or ADO API?

I was expecting all resources to be listed somewhere in the response.

Comment: the only info I was able to get is the branch, repo name, and commit ID of the "main" repository> Can you share your powershell code that you tried also the image of Resources tab that you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Azure DevOps REST API "[**Runs - Get**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)" to get the repository resources used by a pipeline run.

Below is the script samples as reference.

- PowerShell script.

```
$pat = "{PAT}"
$org = "{organization}"
$proj = "{project}"
$pipId = {pipelineId}
$runId = {runId}

$url="https://dev.azure.com/${org}/${proj}/_apis/pipelines/${pipId}/runs/${runId}?api-version=7.0"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $url -Headers $headers
Write-Host ($response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)
```

[image]

- Bash script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

pat="{PAT}"
org="{organization}"
proj="{project}"
pipId={pipelineId}
runId={runId}

url="https://dev.azure.com/$org/$proj/_apis/pipelines/$pipId/runs/$runId?api-version=7.0"
response=$(curl -X GET -u :$pat $url)
echo $response | jq '.'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I was looking for.